# Obtaining Facebook publish_pages permission for user page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

As admin on multiple user pages, some may require that I upload a video. It appears that I need to get the **publish_pages** permission from the page owner.

From my application, how do I get the permission from the owner? It looks like I have to issue an FB login command with an option. From my desktop application, do I need to use the FB JS SDK to get the owner to login to FB and grant me permission?

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously? Someone downvotes the question but doesn't even leave a comment to explain why? Very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn’t have to be the JS SDK, can be the server-side login flow instead for example. But you will need to use some sort of webview/browser component to call the login dialog _in_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to get the "publish_pages" permission added. There are actually several steps to accomplish this:

- create an app to be associated with your page enable Facebook Login    - on the app for the OAuth redirect url, enter    "http://localhost:8080/signin/facebook"
- also make sure the Client OAuth Login" is enabled
- subscribe the page to the app (using Graph API)
- use the sample project [spring-social-quickstart](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples)
- in the signin.html file, put in "publish_pages" into the scope (remove    existing value)
- build/run the app and click on the "Sign in to Facebook" button.

If all is successful, you'll be prompted to allow the new permission to be added.

Answer (score 0):

well, im no some sort of op user here, but last few week im working integrating fbapis whit my site, you need to ask about page token, and after get that permision (from fb) you can do test in your app.

for testing you can get the code from graph explorer. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started this link will be usefull for you,

imnot a english native, so, sorry if any mistake.